# Scaling of double convolution

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, integration

I am interested in the scaling of

$$F(x_1,x_4)=\int_{\mathbb R^2} e^{-\vert x_1 -x_2 \vert -\varepsilon \vert x_2 -x_3 \vert- \vert x_3 -x_4 \vert } \ dx_2 dx_3 $$

In particular, I suspect that

$$F(x_1,x_4) \le C \varepsilon^{-n} e^{-{\varepsilon}\vert x_1 -x_4\vert}$$
for some universal $C>0$ and $n \ge 0$.

But this is really only based on pure heuristic and I do not know which $n$ could be optimal here.

Comment: This integral can be performed exactly. I'll write it down in a little while if nobody else does - first, dinner ...

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt I did mean that, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$$F(x_1,x_4)$ is $8/\ep$ times a value of the convolution of two copies of a pdf with maximum value $1/2$ and a pdf with maximum value $\ep/2$. So,
$$F(x_1,x_4)\le(8/\ep)\min(1/2,1/2,\ep/2)=4\min(1/\ep,1)$$
for all real $x_1,x_4$.

---

The straightforward integration gives
$$F(x_1,x_4)=2\frac{\ep e^{-\left| x\right| } \left(\ep^2 (\left| x\right| +1)-\left| x\right| -3\right)+2
   e^{-\ep \left| x\right| }}{\left(1-\ep^2\right)^2}$$
for $\ep\in(0,1)\cup(1,\infty)$, with
$$F(x_1,x_4)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-|x|} \left(x^2+3|x|+3\right)$$
for $\ep=1$, where $x:=x_4-x_1$, for all real $x_1,x_4$.

In particular, for each $\ep_*\in(0,1)$ and all $\ep\in(0,\ep_*]$,
$$F(x_1,x_4)\le C(\ep_*)e^{-\ep\left|x_4-x_1\right| }$$
for some real $C(\ep_*)>0$ depending only on $\ep_*$ and all real $x_1,x_4$.

Comment: are you sure there is no decay as $\vert x_1 -x_4 \vert$ become large?

Comment: @KungYao : I did not say that there would be no decay -- but the original version of your question allowed even for **growth**.

Comment: I reproduce this result. $\epsilon $ has to satisfy the constraint $1+\epsilon >0$ for $F(x_1,x_4)$ to converge.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt : Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Using $|x|+\epsilon |x-w| \geq (1-\epsilon)|x| +\epsilon |w|$, for  $\epsilon <1$ twice (one for the integral in $dx_2$, the other for $dx_3$), one gets $F(x_1,x_4) \leq \frac{C}{(1-\epsilon)^2 }e^{-\epsilon |x_1-x_4|}$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : Good point!